# Need for on click display responsive menus using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In below code the Purchase, sale, and new menus have some multilevel menus which need to open onClick using jQuery also when click on another menu the first one multilevel menu should be close and then this menu should be open with some transition effects.

```js
$('#handle').on('click', function() {
  $('ul').toggleClass('showing');
});
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).next('li li').toggleClass('showingg');
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#handle {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-transition: linear 0.4s;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #0C9;
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li a:hover {
  background: #333;
}
li ul {
  display: none;
}
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
}
ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #handle {
    display: block;
    background: #066;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: xx-large;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li a:hover {
    background: #0C9;
  }
  .showing {
    max-height: 200em;
  }
  li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  /*li li {
  display:none;
 }*/
  li li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  li li a {
    background: #CCC;
  }
  .showingg {
    display: block;
    ;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav1.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="showing">
      <div id="handle">Menu</div>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Available stock</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Purchase +</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Purchase Return +</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Return1</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sale +</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Sale Return +</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Return2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cash Recieve</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cash Payment</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">New +</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">New Product</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">New Supplier</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">New Town</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">New Customer</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Opening Stock</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gate Pass</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sale History</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Please edit my code." That's not what we do here. You need to address the problem you have and give specifics on what your issue is, and then we can elect to help. We will not simply edit your code.